# Creating folder shortcut on windows programmatically

Tags: c++, shell, winapi

I'm trying to create shortcut to folder programmatically as it would be by right-clicking on a folder->create short cut

I'm doing it using

```
IShellLink*   pShellLink;
IPersistFile* pPersistFile;
//........
hRes = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, 
            (LPVOID*)&pShellLink);
//.....
hRes = pShellLink->SetPath(pszTargetfile);
hRes = pShellLink->SetArguments(pszTargetargs);
if (wcslen(pszDescription) > 0)
{
    hRes = pShellLink->SetDescription(pszDescription);
}
if (wcslen(pszCurdir) > 0)
{
    hRes = pShellLink->SetWorkingDirectory(pszCurdir);
}
if (wcslen(pszIconfile) > 0 && iIconindex >= 0)
{
    hRes = pShellLink->SetIconLocation(pszIconfile, iIconindex);
}
hRes = pShellLink->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*)&pPersistFile);
if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
{
    wcscpy_s(wszLinkfile, pszLinkfile);
    hRes = pPersistFile->Save(wszLinkfile, TRUE);
    pPersistFile->Release();
}
pShellLink->Release();
//....
```

After that I get XXX.lnk file. Then I double click it and see the window "Open With" instead of redirecting to the destinaiton folder.
I found in my lnk properties that the target type is set to 'File' instead of 'File folder' (as in the case of creating a shortcut manually)

It should work as symlink but I need it to be a shortcut (so I don't use **CreateSymbolicLink**)

How to do it properly?

Comment: You don't appear to be setting the link's target - you need to call either `IShellLink::SetPath` or `IShellLink::SetIDList`.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter I use SetPath (I've updated the code), but how to use SetIDList?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out - the slashes in the destination path must be backward